# What am i missing from my interface or assemblies?

Tags: c#, interface, azureservicebus, azure-storage-queues

I have this following interface IQueueClient implements AZureBus class;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus;


namespace MessageQueueApp
{
    public class AZBus:IQueueService
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string QueueName { get; set; }

        private static IQueueClient queueClient;
        public void Send(string payload)
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ConnectionString, QueueName);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
            queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait();
        }


    }
}
```

I am getting an error on my new object name QueueClient() with argument types ConnectionString, QueueName. As well my SendAsync(message).Wait(); What am i missing from this code? Please help and show me guidance to this, thanks.

Comment: And the error is what?

Comment: The type or namespace QueueClient could not be found(are you missing an assembly or directive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
```

Comment: But i am still getting same error even if i used this assembly. It has to do with the IQueueClient queueClient, from the scope it sees it. "Im still thinking ways around this...."